# JPA/Hibernate, @OneToMany and constraints (Oracle)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, constraints

I have the following scenario:

```
@Entity
class A {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long dbId;

  @OneToMany ( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
  @JoinColumn( name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "DBID" )
  Set<C> setOfCs;

}

@Entity
class B {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long dbId;

  @OneToMany ( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
  @JoinColumn( name = "B_ID", referencedColumnName = "DBID" )
  Set<C> setOfCs;

}

@Entity
class C {

    @Id
@GeneratedValue
private long dbId;

}
```

Table C is created with two columns A_ID and B_ID as foreign keys to A.DBID and B.DBID respectively. This makes little sense in my case as each element of C is either linked from A or (xor) B but not both at the same time (both relationships are one-to-many not many-to-many).

Is there a way to have the same tables (which are fine) without the foreign key constraint on A_ID and B_ID? When I set A->C Oracle complains that C.B_ID is not set.

Thanks

Matteo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use @JoinTable? it will remove any foreign key on table C.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinTable(name = "A_B_TABLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID") },      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DB_ID") })
public Set<C> getSetOfCs() {
    return setOfCs;
}
```

and by the way do not annotate  items, do it on its getters instead.

Comment: That does avoid this problem, but it does it by weakening referential integrity: if both the A-C and B-C relationships are handled with join tables, then it is impossible to ensure that there is some kind of relationship.

Comment: Also, you're mistaken to imply that getter access is better than field access; it's mostly a matter of taste, and there are [arguments either way](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/06/jpa-implementation-patterns-field-access-vs-property-access/) - i find the arguments in favour of field access completely persuasive, as it happens.

Comment: Thanks this solves my problem. Yes it will lose some integrity checks on the DB level but these are (or should) be ensured by our application. It would have been also nice to have the same DB structure as in the original example with nullable foreign keys. Since in the real app we have many relations to table `C` we will have many additional tables but in a first test does not seem to be a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of to do this is to force both relationships through a common class, to which C can have a foreign key.

The simplest way to do this would be to introduce some class X which would be a superclass of A and B, and would have the dbId and setOfCs properties. C's table would then have a column X_ID.

Alternatively, make C abstract, and introduce subclasses Ca and Cb, such that instances of A always referred to instances of Ca, and instances of B to Cb. Each of Ca and Cb would only need a single foreign key. This might be very awkward to use, though; amongst other things, it would mean you could never transfer an instance of C from an A to a B.

If you weren't in a position to introduce any base classes, you could apply [Wheeler's law](http://www.dmst.aueb.gr/dds/pubs/inbook/beautiful_code/html/Spi07g.html) and plaster on a layer of indirection, combining both the above approaches. Create an abstract class X, and give it the dbId and setOfCs properties from A and B; C then has a phantom ManyToOne relationship to X, and it table has the corresponding foreign key. Create two concrete subclasses of X, Xa and Xb, each having a OneToOne relationship with an instance of A or B respectively, those instances of A and B having corresponding OneToOne relationships pointing in the other direction.

Comment: Yes I also thought on changing the model but this would have been (for several reasons) only my last resort option.